# Corporate finance exercise book

Tags: finance

I'm preparing a corporate finance exam and I need a book with illustrated exercises that make you really understand the subject, since the written exam is not much mechanical, but more similar to "understand concepts, then juggle with them". I was thinking about using the wiley study guide for the CFA exam, but I need suggestions if it is adequate or not for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The famous textbook of [Brealey Myers and Allen](http://www.amazon.de/Principles-Corporate-Finance-Global-Edition/dp/0077151569) provides tons of exercises ranging from easy to understand up to quite hard problems for the whole range of Corporate Finance related topics.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not saying corporate finance isn't a part of quantitative finance, it's more traditionally viewed as just "finance". The Wiley book is heavily focused on quantitative finance, such as option pricing. It's not something that you'll need for your corporate finance exam. Therefore, I think the Wiley book is simply too advanced for a CFA exam. You should consider something else, such as the book recommended by @muffin1974.